# When my hidden select form is shown it will not call javascript function

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, hidden

I have a hidden select element with an onchange call to a javascript function.

When a user clicks a button on my page I run the below code and my select form is shown:

```
$("#moreDetails2").show();
$('#moreDetails2').trigger("create");
```

After it is shown however, it will not execute its JavaScript function. I have tested it not hidden and it works.

```
<div id = \"moreDetails2\">  
                    <select  onchange=\"moreDetails2($userID,'$id')\">

                        <option value=\"0\">More Options</option>
                        <option value=\"1\"> View Taste Profile</option>
                        <option value=\"2\"> Add Taste Tags</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
```

Looking in inspect element in chrome, I do not get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile don't play well with onchange="... or onclick="... event binding, you will need to do it by manually like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#test-button', function(){     
        $("#moreDetails2").show();
        $("#moreDetails2 select").css('display','block').selectmenu('refresh');
    });    

    $("#moreDetails2 select").on( "change", function(event, ui) {
        moreDetails2('aaaa');
    });    
});

function moreDetails2(text) {
    alert(text);
}
```

And here's a working jsFiddle example created from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/DpdXY/

Answer (score 0):

Using the same name as a global function name and an element identifier will cause problems in Chrome, Safari, and IE (not Firefox).

Try changing your event handler function name to "moreDetailsTwo" or something.

Chrome, Safari, and IE create global symbols (that is, `window` properties) for each element with an "id" value.  I suspect that that's clobbering your binding of the "moreDetails2" function.